# Looking for partial text inside another text across 4 columns in excel

Tags: excel, text, cells

I have text in columns A and B that I want to compare to text that I have in G and H.
Column B contains only partial text, while column H contains the text I'm looking for. Columns A and G are the category - so I'm only interested in the text if the values of A and G are the same (i.e. if the category is the same).

Example:

[image]

`E2` should then equal: "fun in amsterdam"

Comment: can you add some example, please.

Comment: @user3362260 If my answer works for you, please mark it as "The Answer"! (And give simoco's comment on my answer an upvote while you're at it!) Thanks! :)

Comment: Its very difficult to explain and I cant post a screenshot, let me try: Columns A and G are categories - city names to be specific, while columns B and H are things to do in these cities (column B has only partial text, while column H has the text I'm looking for). So say A2 is "Amsterdam" and then B2 is be "fun", G2 is Amsterdam again and H2 is "fun in amsterdam", so the answer to my query, which I would add to  E2 is "fun in amsterdam". Of course I have thousands of rows to look through

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the partial match has to be CaSe SeNsItIvE, use this:

```
=IF(AND(A1=G1,ISNUMBER(FIND(B1,H1))),"Found","Not Found")
```

If the partial match doesn't need to be case sensitive, so "xyz" is in "XYZ123", use this:

```
=IF(AND(A1=G1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,H1))),"Found","Not Found")
```

(The case-sensitivity tip came from @simoco !)

And if you want to return the case-sensitive value of H1, use this:

```
=IF(AND(A1=G1,ISNUMBER(FIND(B1,H1))),H1,"")
```

Comment: 1) `find` is case-sensitive, while `search` - not. It would be more reliable to use `search` 2) you could use `=IF(AND(a1=g1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(b1,h1))),"Found","Not Found")` - it doesn't return any errors:)

Comment: Thanks @simoco -- I updated my answer, and then saw that you'd added your comment (with the same solution!!!) 17 seconds before I updated mine. Upvote your comment!

Comment: it's great, but read my first point: `find` is case-sensitive, while `search` - not. I suggest you to use `SEARCH` instead `FIND`:)

Comment: I was thinking about case-sensitivity, and it really depends on the kind of data being analyzed. Product numbers, passwords, etc. are probably case sensitive, so FIND should be used. In other cases, SEARCH would be a lot better. But it really depends on the situation. (But I'll add a comment in my answer.)

Comment: But at least you could mention it in your answer and provide two options for OP:)

Comment: Thanks, it works and returns "found" or "not found", but I'm actually looking for it to return the whole word that is in H2 instead of a binary yes or no answer. Is that possible?

Comment: @BrettFromLA  
Thanks a lot for that! it works and returns "found" or "not found", but I'm actually looking for the formula to return the whole word that is in H2: "fun in amsterdam" instead of a binary yes or no answer. Is that possible?

Comment: @BrettFromLA Hi, thanks again! I think I did not explain an important part: the list does not match horizontally. There are at least other 50 categories (city names) and each category has many "partial" words inside or if. Also, I might have only 3 partial words in the category Amsterdam (b2, b3, b4 respectively), but I might have dozens of full words in column H to scan through.  Basically the formula needs to look at all of the categories and words vertically. I hope that makes sense. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3362260 Wow! My answer really only works for one row. To accomplish what you're talking about, I would write a macro in VBA. But that's a completely separate question. You should probably repost this question with that information, and include a larger screenshot that shows multiple rows. The screenshot will give people answering the question a better sense of how tricky this challenge is! :)

Comment: Thanks Brett, at least now I have peace of mind that I can't do that with a simple formula :)

Comment: @user3362260 Well ... you might be able to, if you use VLookup. That can find matching text within a range of cells. A coworker of mine uses it all the time, but I've only peeked at it once or twice.